# The consequences of not closing a PrintWriter object

Tags: java, theory, printwriter

I wrote a really basic program which takes 2 equally sized lists of temperatures and creates a .CSV file using them. The weird part is that when I forgot to close the PrintWriter object and ran the program the output file was missing 300ish results (I don't know which results were missing) and depending on how the comma in the println was written either like this ", " or like this "," it would be missing a different number of results. When I closed the PrintWriter regardless of how the comma was written the output file would have the correct number of results. I was just wondering if anyone could explain why this was happening I thought closing the PrintWriter would just close it in the same was as closing a Scanner object would?

Don't have access to the code right now but it was just a for loop which would print the value of the current index of the 2 arrays in this format

```
PrintWriter.println(list1.get[i] + "," + list2.get[i];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, output is collected in memory and only written to disk from time to time. This is done since larger disk writes are much more efficient.

When you don't close the writer you miss the last buffer full of output. But there are other negative consequences as well, the file will stay open until the program exits. If you do this repeatedly it will lead to resource leaks.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the writer content not being properly flushed and thus getting partially lost, every open writer hogs resources (RAM and OS file handles), and also blocks the file from being accessed by other processes.

Always close every writer and reader once you're done with it.